# How to eliminate Claims with ClaimStatus = 1 based on Activity Date. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 3 different claims in my dataset.

`ClaimStatus` can be only 1 or 0. Which indicates Open (0) or Closed (1).

How to eliminate those claims that have the last `ClaimStatus = 1`.

[image]

I tried to use `Last_Value` function in my `WHERE` clause but got an error:

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses

Query result should return only `Claim2`, because `ClaimStatus` is still open:

[image]

Code:

```
declare @TempTable table 
                   (
                        ClaimNumber varchar(50), 
                        ActivityID int, 
                        Activity varchar(50), 
                        ActivityDate datetime, 
                        ClaimStatus int
                   )

insert into @TempTable 
values ('Claim1', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-05-04 10:58:56.510', 0),
       ('Claim1', 4, 'ReserveCreated', '2018-05-09 09:52:52.327', 0),
       ('Claim1', 6, 'PaymentCreated', '2018-05-15 13:17:47.920', 0),
       ('Claim1', 8, 'ClaimClosed', '2018-11-01 10:53:00.087', 1),
       ('Claim2', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-05-04 10:58:56.510', 0),
       ('Claim2', 4, 'ReserveCreated', '2018-05-09 09:52:52.327', 0),
       ('Claim2', 6, 'PaymentCreated', '2018-05-15 13:17:47.920', 0),
       ('Claim3', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-05-04 10:58:56.510', 0),
       ('Claim3', 4, 'ReserveCreated', '2018-05-09 09:52:52.327', 0),
       ('Claim3', 6, 'PaymentCreated', '2018-05-15 13:17:47.920', 0),
       ('Claim3', 8, 'ClaimClosed', '2018-11-01 10:53:00.087', 1)

select *
from @TempTable
where LAST_VALUE(ClaimStatus) over (partition by ClaimNumber order by ActivityDate desc) <> 1
```

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: How many `ClaimStatus` are there?

Comment: Only 2 ClaimStatus. Either 1 or 0

Comment: Can a claim be reopened? So the 1 would be somewhere other than on the most recent line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/RWKN13932)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT ClaimNumber, 
           ClaimStatus,
           ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC) as rn
    FROM @TempTable
)
SELECT t.*
FROM @TempTable t
JOIN (SELECT *
      FROM cte
      WHERE rn = 1) f
  ON t.ClaimNumber = f.ClaimNumber
 AND f.ClaimStatus = 0
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Additionally if only 2 status you also can do

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT ClaimNumber
    FROM @TempTable
    GROUP BY ClaimNumber
    HAVING MAX(ClaimStatus) = 0
)
SELECT t.*
FROM @TempTable t
WHERE ClaimNumber IN (SELECT * FROM cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can't put `LAST_VALUE` in the `WHERE`, but you can put it in the `SELECT` of a CTE, and then reference that in the `WHERE`:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ClaimNumber,
           ActivityID,
           Activity,
           ActivityDate,
           ClaimStatus,
           LAST_VALUE(ClaimStatus) OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimNumber ORDER BY ActivityDate
                                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS LatestStatus
    FROM @TempTable)
SELECT ClaimNumber,
       ActivityID,
       Activity,
       ActivityDate,
       ClaimStatus
FROM CTE
WHERE LatestStatus != 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question right, it seems like what you're interested in is finding out if the last status of a claim is that it's closed. If that's correct, we just need to find the last record and then check it's status. This seems to work:

```
SELECT
  tt.ClaimNumber,
  tt.ClaimStatus
FROM
  @TempTable AS tt
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      t.ClaimNumber
     ,MAX(t.ActivityDate) AS LastActivity
    FROM
      @TempTable AS t
    GROUP BY
      t.ClaimNumber
  )          AS s
    ON
    s.ClaimNumber = tt.ClaimNumber
      AND s.LastActivity = tt.ActivityDate
WHERE
  tt.ClaimStatus <> 1;
```

Results:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| ClaimNumber | ClaimStatus |
+-------------+-------------+
| Claim2      |           0 |
+-------------+-------------+
```