# How to select claims that been created and no activities been done on them for more then 10 days.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The claim is created, and then sequence of activities (with ActivityDate) will be perform on that Claim until it closed.

`ActivityID` `= 0` means `Claim` been created.

The goal is to display only those claims that been created and no Activities been done for more than 10 days from today.

In the example below, `Claim2` and `Claim4` was created more than 10 ago and no activities has been done on them after that.

[image]

```
declare @TempTable table (ClaimNumber varchar(50), ActivityID int, Activity varchar(50), ActivityDate datetime, ClaimStatus int)
insert into @TempTable values   ('Claim1', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-05-04', 0 ),
                                ('Claim1', 4, 'ReserveCreated', '2018-05-09', 0 ),
                                ('Claim1', 6, 'PaymentCreated', '2018-05-15', 0 ),
                                ('Claim1', 8, 'ClaimClosed', '2018-11-01', 1 ),
                                ('Claim2', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-11-01', 0 ),                          
                                ('Claim3', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-05-04', 0 ),
                                ('Claim3', 4, 'ReserveCreated', '2018-05-09', 0 ),
                                ('Claim3', 6, 'PaymentCreated', '2018-05-15', 0 ),
                                ('Claim4', 0, 'ClaimCreated', '2018-11-10', 0 )

select * from @TempTable
```

So how can I display only `Claim2` and `Claim4`?

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service site.  What have you tried???  `select* from @TempTable`  is not trying.

Comment: Just because you got a (free) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53506245/how-to-eliminate-claims-with-claimstatus-1-based-on-activity-date-sql2012) doesn't mean mean you can post another question and expect another (free) answer without showing your attempts again. Please have a look at the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which states: *"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."*

Comment: The users here are more than happy to help you, but you have enough reputation to know you should be showing your efforts when asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
(
    select *,
           cnt = count(*) over (partition by ClaimNumber order by ActivityDate
                                rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following),
           diff_date = DATEDIFF(d, ActivityDate, SYSDATETIME())
    from @TempTable 
) x
where cnt = 1 and diff_date > 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a WHERE NOT EXISTS() clause.

Answer (score 1):

here you go bud

```
select *
from (
select *
,TimeBetweenPayments_1 = datediff(day,[ClaimCreated],[ReserveCreated])
,TimeBetweenPayments_2 = datediff(day,[ReserveCreated],[PaymentCreated])
,TimeBetweenPayments_3 = datediff(day,[PaymentCreated],[ClaimClosed])
from (
select *
from (
select ClaimNumber, ActivityDate,Activity
--,Rank_1 = Row_number() over(partition by ClaimNumber order by ActivityDate asc)
from @TempTable
) as a
pivot (
max(ActivityDate)
    FOR Activity IN ([ClaimCreated], [ReserveCreated], [PaymentCreated], [ClaimClosed])
) as pvt
) c
)d
where (TimeBetweenPayments_1 is null or TimeBetweenPayments_1 > 10 )
```